# Change data on two different querys from React Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

so im doing a little application of a pokedex utilizing the pokeapi to test react query, what i am trying to do is first fetch the data on mount and after that, if i use the search button the data already fetched to change something like this
[fetch on mount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu5Ng.png)
and the search
[search fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXSSt.png)

something easy to do with useState but i am having problems with react query

i got something like this
[pokedex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHJFS.png)
at the mount of the component i have this

```
export const fetchPokemon = async (URL: string) => {
  const result = await axios.get<pokemon>(URL);
  return result;
};

export const fetchPokemons = async () => {
  const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0s";
  const { data } = await axios.get<pokemons>(URL);
  const result = await Promise.all(
    data.results.map(async (pokemon) => {
      return fetchPokemon(pokemon.url);
    })
  );
  return result;
};

export const useAllPokemons = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["pokemons"],
    queryFn: fetchPokemons,
  });
};

const { data, isLoading } = useAllPokemons();
```

works great but now i want to search pokemons with a search button like in the image and to replace the initial data that i already fetch so only the data that i searched appears so i did this

```
export const fetchAllPokemons = async () => {
  const URL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100";
  const { data } = await axios.get<pokemons>(URL);
  const result = await Promise.all(
    data.results.map(async (pokemon) => {
      return fetchPokemon(pokemon.url);
    })
  );
  return result;
};

  let { data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["pokemons"],
    queryFn: fetchAllPokemons,
    enabled: false,
    select: (data) => {
      const pokemonData = data.map((pokemon) => {
        if (pokemon.data.name.startsWith("char")) {
          return pokemon;
        }
      });
      return pokemonData;
    },
  });

<button
        onClick={() => {
          refetch();
        }}
      >
        asd
      </button>
```

and nothing happens, but when i open the console the data is changing but then again returns to the initial fetch

Comment: What is the difference between `fetchPokemons` in your first code block and  `fetchAllPokemons` in your second code block, is it a typo?

Comment: oh I forget to put its a more broad fetch but instead of limit=20 its limit=100

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the onSuccess:

```js
const {data} = useQuery("fetchData", fetchData, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
     // do something with your data and return
    
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried but happens the same thing, the data recharges the global fetch